# more space between lines and Text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make something like this:

```
      ---------------------        WORK         ------------------
                           ---------------------
```

Heres my Code

```css
h2 { 
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    line-height:0.1em;
    margin:10px 0 20px; 
} 
h2 span { 
    background:#fff; 
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>THIS IS A TEST</span></h2>
```

I tried a lot with making many changes, but couldnt.Please let me know what to do here?

Comment: I can't say what you are actually asking, but if your desired output is the text above, then try this: ` <pre>---------------------        WORK         ------------------
                           ---------------------</pre>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, what you are looking for is a dashed border: `border-bottom: 1px dashed black`.

```css
h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
}

h2 span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>WORK</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code:

```
<div class='white-line'></div>
    <div  class='line-title text-center' >
    <span class='bg-black'>THIS IS A TEST</span>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.white-line{ height: 0; border-top: 1px;}
.bg-black{ background-color: #000000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try somethings like this:

```css
    h2 { 
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        line-height:0.1em;
        margin:10px 0 20px; 
    } 
    h2 span { 
        background:#fff; 
        padding:0 10px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-top-width: 0;
        border-left-width: 0;
        border-right-width: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <h2><span>THIS IS A TEST</span></h2>
```

This example is with `solid` border, you can change it with `dashed` if you want dashed border.